# Parsing JSON in RestKit with dynamic data

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, restkit

I am trying to parse the following JSON but i am getting the following error.

"Error Could not find an object mapping for keyPath: '' "

As far as i understand it is because I havent provided a SetMapping: forKeyPath: but i cannot set this because the key will change as you can see in the JSON e.g. BBC ONE, BBC TWO and so on.
I do not need to save the service name as i plan on cross referencing the SID with another json file that contains these details stored in core data to provide this. (if its possible).
Is there a way around this error?

Here is my JSON (cut down version)

```
{
    "BBC ONE": [
        {
            "Name": "Programme 1",
            "Description": "A desc of a programme",
            "ONID": 1,
            "TSID": 2,
            "SID": 3,
            "CRID": "crid_address"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Programme 2",
            "Description": " Another desc",
            "ONID": 9,
            "TSID": 99,
            "SID": 999,
            "CRID": "crid_2"
        }
    ],
    "BBC TWO": [
        {
            "Name": "bbc_programme",
            "Description": "programme 2",
            "Event ID": 4,
            "ONID": 9,
            "TSID": 4,
            "SID": 4,
            "CRID": "crid"
        }
    ]
}
```

and more.

Here is my code:

```
RKManagedObjectMapping *epgMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Epg class] inManagedObjectStore:objectManager.objectStore];

        [epgMapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes:@"Name",@"name",
                                        @"Description", @"desc",
                                        @"Event ID", @"event_id",
                                        @"ONID", @"onid",
                                        @"TSID", @"tsid",
                                        @"SID",  @"sid",
                                        @"CRID", @"crid",nil];


    epgMapping.primaryKeyAttribute = @"crid";
```

Any Help would be appreciated as i have read various documents and looked at other peoples issue and cannot find a solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're storing a value in the name portion of the json name-value pair.  Suggest changing your json (if you can) to something like this:

```
"Name" : "BBC ONE",
"Programs" : [
    {
        "Name": "Programme 1",
        "Description": "A desc of a programme",
        "ONID": 1,
        "TSID": 2,
        "SID": 3,
        "CRID": "crid_address"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Programme 2",
        "Description": " Another desc",
        "ONID": 9,
        "TSID": 99,
        "SID": 999,
        "CRID": "crid_2"
    }
```

Comment: OK, i thought i might have to change the structure but was hoping someone else might have an idea of how to parse it.